# How to define chrome.bluetooth successfully?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am looking for a minimal working example of a bluetooth low energy object for chrome such that:

```
chrome.bluetooth
```

returns something other than

```
undefined
```

from javascript at runtime.

I've tried various incarnations of manifest.json including:

```
{
  "name": "Bluetooth Low Energy Test App",
  "description": "App testing the chrome.bluetoothLowEnergy API",
  "version": "0.1",
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
  },
  "bluetooth": {
    "low_energy": true
  }
}
```

and

```
{
  "name": "Bluetooth Low Energy Test App",
  "description": "App testing the chrome.bluetoothLowEnergy API",
  "version": "0.1",
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
  },
  "bluetooth": {}
}
```

and

```
{
    "name": "Bluetooth Low Energy Test App",
    "description": "App testing the chrome.bluetoothLowEnergy API",
    "version": "0.1",
    "app": {
        "background": {
            "scripts": ["background.js"]
        }
    },
    "bluetooth": {
        "profiles": [
            "00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb" // array of uuids
        ]
    }
}
```

but none of these yield a working chrome.bluetooth instance in the javascript console.

I've tested this on Chrome 42 and 44 on Mac OS X and ChromeOS with bluetooth enabled. Both machines have bluetooth turned on and can see the BTLE devices.

Does chrome.bluetooth work on any version of Chrome on any platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing link was that the HTML and JavaScript described by the manifest.json must be installed as a chrome extension. The easiest way to achieve this is to download a zip of the app from github, unzip it to downloads, and then:

1. click menu/more tools/extensions
2. click developer mode checkbox
3. click load unpacked extension
4. select the unzipped folder of HTML/CSS/JSON
5. goto developer tools
6. examine the chrome.bluetooth instance
7. examine the chrome.bluetoothLowEnergy instance

On my chromebook, all of these were defined no matter which version of chrome I used.

I'm running an Acer C720P.

The chrome extension was the missing link for me. I should've known from the manifest.json.

I'm thinking of making a pull request to the docs for chrome.bluetooth and chrome.bluetoothLowEnergy to mention the extension requirement, as it was not obvious to me, but I assume this stems from the sandboxing required given the local filesystem vs. remote URI. It does seem a little weird that you don't get a prompt about the bluetooth access, given the behavior of GPS chipsets and the like.

Answer (score 0):

I never use this api but take a look at *developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/bluetooth*

Also *developer.chrome.com/apps/bluetoothLowEnergy* and *developer.chrome.com/apps/bluetoothSocket* both since Chrome 37.

Here is (I think what are you looking for) a better example and explanation of how to use it (examples of get devices, discover devices, etc) [Good stuff](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_bluetooth)

**Anothers examples apps:**

*github.com/armansito/ble-battery-service-demo/blob/master/script.js*
*github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/bluetooth-samples/device-info-demo*

Sorry about the plain text links, have not reputation for paste more than 2...